# C# Automapper, Cannot implicitly convert for Task return type

Tags: c#, automapper

I know it looks simple, but I have spent quite some time on this.

Somehow I could not return list successfully...

```
public Task<List<MyViewModel>> getGoodElections(long actionId)
{
    var elections = _DBsource.ElectionTable.Where(e => e.ActionId == actionId && e.Status == "OK").ToListAsync();
    List< MyViewModel > list = Mapper.Map<List<MyViewModel>>(elections);
    return list;

}
```

At "return list;", it's giving me error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyViewModel>` to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyViewModel>>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you returning a task from a non-async method? If you must, you can `return Task.FromResult(list)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not awaiting the result of your database call. As a consequence, the `elections` returned from the DB call is of type `Task<>` of whatever the DTO type is that your DB call returns (i.e. even if you return a `Task`, AutoMapper won't be able to map the result anyway).

You need to make the method `async`, and then await the result of the DB call, before passing it off to Automapper to map.

```
public async Task<List<MyViewModel>> getGoodElections(long actionId)
{
    var elections = await _DBsource.ElectionTable
       .Where(e => e.ActionId == actionId && e.Status == "OK")
       .ToListAsync();
    var list = Mapper.Map<List<MyViewModel>>(elections);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before posting this question. but I got this error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<Task<List<MyViewModel>>>

Comment: @Henrix The error message is pretty explicit in what it's telling you to do.  Do that.

Comment: @Henrix Yes indeed, and that is why we've added the `async` modifer as mentioned :)

Comment: @Henrix I think you have a second task in there by mistake :P

Comment: How stupid I was. Yes, I missed out the 'async'...:D

Answer (score 0):

You haven't awaited the Task (ToListAsync), so you don't have a `List<Election>`. You should await the call to ToListAsync() and mark the method as async like below.

```
public async Task<List<MyViewModel>> getGoodElections(long actionId)
{
    var elections = await _DBsource.ElectionTable.Where(e => e.ActionId == actionId && e.Status == "OK").ToListAsync();
    List< MyViewModel > list = Mapper.Map<List<MyViewModel>>(elections);
    return list;

}
```